# ¿Cómo eliminar los espacios en blanco en la salida de una consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero consultar una lista ordenada alfabéticamente de todos los nombres en OCCUPATIONS, **seguidos inmediatamente** por la primera letra de cada profesión como paréntesis (es decir: encerrados entre paréntesis). Por ejemplo: NombreDeActor(A), NombreDeMédico(D), NombreDeProfesor(P) y NombreDeCantante(S).

Entonces intenté:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT NAME, '(', LEFT(OCCUPATION,1),')' FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY NAME ASC
) T;
```

Pero me devuelve un extrano espacios en blanco despues de cada elemento:

```
Jenny ( S )

Julia ( D )

Ketty ( A )

Kristeen ( S )

Maria ( P )

Meera ( P )

Naomi ( P )

Priya ( D )

Priyanka ( P )

Samantha ( A )
```

Comment: Tu explicación es muy poco clara. Estás seleccionando 4 columnas distintas. Si la columna `name` u `ocupation` tienen espacios, es porque así están almacenadas en la base de datos. Si le llamas _espacios_ al hecho de que están separadas es, bueno, porque las estás pidiendo de esa manera. Por otro lado, ¿porqué haces un `select from (select`? pregunto, porque no le veo el sentido en este caso...

Comment: @jachguate desafordunadamente la columnas name u ocupation no tienen espacios espacios en la base de datos. Así es como salen con la consulta. CONCAT deshacerse de ellas. Tienes razon no habia No necesitaba un SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... como lo muestra Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías usar mejor la función [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html). De esta manera puedes concatenar cadenas con campos que necesites extraer de la BD.

La consulta sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT CONCAT(NAME, "(", LEFT(OCCUPATION,1), ")")
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```